# AWS codedeploy using S3 revisions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have been using AWS CodeDeploy for a couple months, but I have been using git Commit ID as my revision. I am not trying to auto deploy after success on CI server. They service requires we use S3 for revisions.

But when I try to use S3 I get the following DownloadBundle lifecycle method:

- For my CodeDeploy error

`HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS`

- In my logs ec2 logs

`Error CodeUnknownError
Script Name
Messagecannot load such file -- aws-sdk-core/s3
Log Tail`

Things I have checked already:

1. User has permissions -- it is me and I have all permission :)
2. EC2 instances and S3 bucket are in the same region
3. I have manually download the revision and it is correct

This appears to be a stacktrace from the error

`` 2017-01-13 20:28:04 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(19081)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: LoadError - cannot load such file -- aws-sdk-core/s3 - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:200:in `download_from_s3'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:76:in `block in <class:CommandExecutor>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:62:in `execute_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:132:in `process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:65:in `perform'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/agent/base.rb:28:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:38:in `block in run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:37:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:70:in `block in run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/runner/child.rb:55:in `with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:69:in `run_with_error_handling'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:33:in `block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in `loop'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/child.rb:22:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:206:in `block in spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:204:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:204:in `spawn_child'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:196:in `block in spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:195:in `times'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:195:in `spawn_children'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:134:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:37:in `block in start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `fork'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/process_manager-0.0.13/lib/process_manager/master.rb:36:in `start'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/../lib/codedeploy-agent.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/command_support.rb:130:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:262:in `block in call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:275:in `call_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/gli-2.5.6/lib/gli/app_support.rb:69:in `run'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/../lib/codedeploy-agent.rb:88:in `<main>' ``

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's complaining about issue while finding the S3 SDK from the SDK core. Have you tried to update the host agent to the latest version or manually import the aws-sdk-core onto the box?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a deploymentId? Or do you mind paste a host agent log on the instance to give more context? The host agent log directory is /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log

Comment: Hey I provided what appears to be a stacktrace from the error in the original question